# Individual values in a dropdownlist using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got a dropdownlist which filters results using jquery ajax. But I can't figure out how to seperate the values in the list.

When I use this code:

```
$("#orderby").on('change', function() {

    $.post("ajax/prijslaaghoog.php", $("#orderby").val('lowhigh'), function(result){
        $("#productviewajax").html(result);
    });

    $.post("ajax/default.php", $("#orderby").val('default'), function(result){
        $("#productviewajax").html(result);
    });
});
```

It runs both php files when I select a value. How can I make it so that only default.php runs when default is selected, and prijslaaghoog.php when lowhigh is selected?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$("#orderby").val('lowhigh')` you are setting the value of the dropdownlist. 
Instead you should filter the option selected:

```
$("#orderby").on('change', function() {

    var strUrl = "ajax/default.php";
    var strFilter = $('#orderby > option').filter(':selected').val();

    if (strFilter  == 'lowhigh'){
        strUrl = "ajax/prijslaaghoog.php";
    }

    $.post(strUrl, { filter: strFilter }, function(result){
        $("#productviewajax").html(result);
    });

});
```

And also, if you have `data` attribute in each option you don't even need an `if statement`:

```
<select id="orderby">
    <option value="default" data-post-url="default.php">Default</option>
    <option value="lowhigh" data-post-url="prijslaaghoog.php">lowhigh</option>
</select>

$("#orderby").on('change', function() {

    var option = $('#orderby > option').filter(':selected');

    $.post("ajax/" + option.data("post-url"), { 
        filter: option.val() 
    }, function(result){
        $("#productviewajax").html(result);
    });

});
```

Comment: Is there a typo maybe in the last script? When I add the data parts not any php script is running.

Comment: Sorri, I've made a mistake, is not `$('#orderby').filter`.. should be `$('#orderby > option').filter`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting if clause before $.post like this:

```
$("#orderby").on('change', function() {
    if ($('#orderby').val() == 'lowhigh'){
        //post here.
    }else if ($('#orderby').val() == 'default'){
        //post here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like below:

```
 $("#orderby").on('change', function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'lowhigh'){
        $.post("ajax/prijslaaghoog.php", $("#orderby").val('lowhigh'), function(result){
            $("#productviewajax").html(result);
        });
     }else if ($(this).val() == 'default'){
       $.post("ajax/default.php", $("#orderby").val('default'), function(result){
            $("#productviewajax").html(result);
        });
    }
});
```